# How to not send data for disabled text areas of deselected check boxes?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I use check boxes to select several text areas. I will have a send button for inputs of selected check boxes so disabled ones wont be sent to server side.

But I cannot really figure out how to not send deselected data by coding PHP. I am not really sure, probably, I should have looked for a JS code.

Comment: What is the question here? Are you trying to filter what inputs get submitted to the server? Because if you are, you just have to disable those inputs and they aren't submitted in the POST request.

Comment: Right, that is a better expression for my problem.

Comment: As far as I know, unselected checkboxes are not send in the request.

Comment: Still not clear what issue is though, just set `disabled` attribute

Comment: Any kind of disabled inputs don't get submitted. And this can be achieved fairly easily with jQuery or pure Javascript.

Comment: OK. Thanks very much for this super easy yet very helpful fact. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything else if your text areas are already disabled:

> Values of disabled controls are not submitted with a form.

[Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/interact/forms.html#h-9.1.4)

Answer (score 0):

you can use :`<INPUT disabled name="fred" value="stone">` for more Details go to [Link](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled)